# Start odometry with bias depending on Pose

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to fuse two localization methods, odometry and a PoseWithCovariance sensor.
When the robot "starts" it already has a location and rotation from the PoseWithCovariance sensor (like x=4 and y=3 etc)
But the odometry is (0,0,0, etc), how do I make sure that both systems start at the same position?

Of course, the two coordinates will change and be different from each other as time goes, which is expected. To get an accurate position I'm going to use an EKF from robot_localization. So I don't need a constant transform between the two, just only at the start.

My odometry uses the odom and base_link frames (as the standard) and the Pose messages has the frame_id odom.

What is the best way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288283/start-odometry-with-bias-depending-on-pose/) by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the robot_localization yaml config file you can specify the "use_relative" parameter  for your pose sensor (e.g., pose0_relative: true). This will make it fuse all the measurements from that sensor relative to the initial measurement. For example, if your first and second pose0 measurements were (4,3) and (5,1), it would fuse these as (0,0) and (1,-2).

On another note - be careful with fusing absolute position measurements from multiple sources. You might consider only fusing velocity measurements from your odometry, or using the r_l "use_differential" parameter for your odometry.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on 2018-04-11**:
So if set the pos and odom to use relative they both start at (0,0) right?
I'll look into the velocity thing. Thank you!